# Google sketchup round corners of straight lines (stroke) as in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketchup

On illustrator, when drawing a series of straight lines, you can choose under "stroke" how the corners of those lines will be: round, bevel and miter.

I'm looking for the same function on sketchup. I've found that under styles - extension, you can extend the end of the line, but not round it. How can I achieve that?

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to style lines in SketchUp, I believe the answer is to spend the money to get SketchUp Pro which has a full range of styling tools to allow you to create themes for how your images are rendered. They call this the 'style builder':

http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/product/stylebuilder.html

Comment: Thanks. As i've stated in my question, i've played around with styles a bit, and i'm positive the answer could lay there. The company i work for owns a copy of pro, but the person who used to work with it is no longer with us.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SketchUp does not directly support rounding edges when you create an edge/face using the line tool.  It does if you draw a rectangle as explained [here](http://support.google.com/sketchup/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95599).

Here's a [link](http://sketchupdate.blogspot.com/2010/07/take-edge-off-roundcorners.html) to a plugin that purportedly supports what you need.  I have not tried it myself but this might be worth checking out.